# Align 2 faces with only two vertices and constraints

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image] I want those 2 faces to be on the same plane only by moving A on the C axis and B on X/Y/Z. I tried to resize with transform orientation to normale but I cannot lock the other vertice position. Maybe a tool displaying the normal numerical values of the two face would help. The rest of the mesh is currently hidden.

Is there a tool or technique to do that ?

Comment: If the right face (viewer's right) is not planar, it cannot be made planar by moving A along C (and B won't affect it).  To move B to the same plane as the right face, select the right face, snap cursor to selection, ctrl alt space create custom orientation, then select B and scale 0 in z to cursor.

Comment: WHen I select a single vertex, with the right face as the transform orientation, scaling do not affect the single point B.

Comment: I haven't found a good solution, so I just displayed huge normals and did my best to align them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused with the question so here are a few options.

To flatten the faces on the $Z$ axis, for example, select all vertices, scale them to zero (press  <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)

You can modify the coordinates for any point numerically. Enter edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) enable the [**Sidebar**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/regions.html#sidebar) (press <kbd>N</kbd>) to access the *Item Properties* panel.

You can see the *Local* and *Global* coordinates and manipulate them at will.

[image]

So you can flatten the faces first and then, with all vertices still selected, you can set them at the correct coordinates numerically.

---

To move a vertex along an existing edge, use [**Vertex Slide**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/slide_vertices.html?highlight=vertex%20slide) (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>V</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: My problem is not so much to move the vertex, it's to put the 2 face on the same plane. They are supposed to be one flat surface.

Comment: As stated on the answer, you can manually set the vertices to be at a specific value on the global the z axis. To flatten al vertices. Select them and scale them on the z axis to zero (press S Z 0), while still selected input the desired value in the z axis using the side panel

Comment: See edited answer